# Issue with "#" in perl

Tags: perl

I am facing an issue which I am not able to understand with the subroutine below:

```
sub password()
{
$StdIn = new Win32::Console(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
my $Password = "";

$StdIn->Mode(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
print "Enter Password: ";

    while (ord(my $Data = $StdIn->InputChar(1)) !=10) 
    { 

               if("\r" eq $Data )
            {
            last;
        }
         elsif ("\ch" eq $Data)
         {
            if( "" ne chop( $Password ))
             {
                print "\ch \ch";
             }
            next;
        }
    $Password .=$Data;
    print "*";
    }

 return $Password;

}
```

The above script works fine with everything unless password contains "#". If it contains "#"
the main subroutine which calls the above subroutine does not get connected with the tool, that I need to automate. Although the tool has no problem with `#` — "it works fine with #" when I use it manually.  So I think there is some issue with Perl itself. Can you please help?

Comment: what is the error you get when you use '#'

Comment: I don't get any error but the script doesn't get connected with the tool that I need to automate.

Comment: Do you have a resource leak because your `$StdIn` is not a `my` variable?  Do you also need to close `$Stdin`?  It would be good to fix the erratic indentation.  You get an upvote simply because your use of '`\ch`' made me go and look at the Perl docs to find out that is a way of representing control characters, so you're using `\ch` as a longwinded way of writing `\b`, like you're using `10` as a way of recognizing `\r` (so your test in the loop is probably redundant).

Comment: Put: "use warnings; use strict;" at the beginning of your script and begin to fix issues like like undeclared variables. Try to debug your script by checking what is the $Password at the end in case of #.

Answer (score 3):

First off, use [Term::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term%3a%3aPrompt) instead of messing around with the console yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Term::Prompt;

my $pass = prompt P => 'Password: ', undef, undef;
print "$pass\n";
```

As for your problem, I am assuming the problem is in the part you don't show. However, note

1. Use `Win32::Console->new` [rather than indirect object syntax](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html).
2. Do use [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).
3. The `*` characters you're printing will not appear until after the password has been entered. Use `local $| = 1` before your `while` if you insist on writing C in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to show the input? Just write print $Data; to see if it accept the input.

Comment: yes I did that and its showing #.But once password is returned to the calling subroutine to get connected with the tool,it is not working with #.

Comment: @gautamkumar Well if your sub returns the correct password maybe the error is in the (not shown) part of your script that actually calls the other application.